# Create a list column with just one item in it (no group by)

Tags: r, tidyr

Here is a workflow that trains an XGB model using tidr list columns, rsmaple folds and purrr map:

```
library(rsample)
library(xgboost)
library(Metrics)

# keep just numeric features for this example
pdata_split <- initial_split(diamonds %>% select(-cut, -color, -clarity), 0.9)
training_data <- training(pdata_split)
testing_data <- testing(pdata_split)

train_cv <- vfold_cv(training_data, 5) %>% 

  # create training and validation sets within each fold
  mutate(train = map(splits, ~training(.x)), 
         validate = map(splits, ~testing(.x)))

# xgb across each fold
mod.xgb <- train_cv %>%

  # convert regression data to a dmatrix for xgb. Just simple price ~ carat for here and now
  mutate(train_dmatrix = map(train, ~xgb.DMatrix(.x %>% select(carat) %>% as.matrix(), label = .x$price)),
         validate_dmatrix = map(validate, ~xgb.DMatrix(.x %>% select(carat) %>% as.matrix(), label = .x$price))) %>% 

  mutate(regression = map(train_dmatrix, ~xgboost(.x, objective = "reg:squarederror", nrounds = 100))) %>% # fit the model
  mutate(predictions =map2(.x = regression, .y = validate_dmatrix, ~predict(.x, .y))) %>% # predictions
  mutate(validation_actuals = map(validate, ~.x$carat)) %>% # get the actuals for computing evaluation metrics
  mutate(mae = map2_dbl(.x = validation_actuals, .y = predictions, ~Metrics::mae(actual = .x, predicted = .y))) %>% # mae
  mutate(rmse = map2_dbl(.x = validation_actuals, .y = predictions, ~Metrics::rmse(actual = .x, predicted = .y))) # rmse
```

My actual script and data uses `crossing()` and other models with their own hyper parameters in order to pick the best model. So, the real block the above is based on allows me to compare several models since it actually contains several models.

I like this workflow because using dplyr verbs and the pipe operator, I can make changes as needed while progressing through each step, then apply them to each fold using map functions.

Now that I'm at the test phase and passed the cross validation phase, I'd like to emulate that 'flow' except I do not have folds so there is no need for map_* functions.

However, I still need to make transformations such as the one above adding an xgb.DMatrix since I am using xgboost.

Example, below what I created to test my chosen xgb model:

```
library(rsample)
library(xgboost)
library(Metrics)

# keep just numeric features for this example
pdata_split <- initial_split(diamonds %>% select(-cut, -color, -clarity), 0.9)
training_data <- training(pdata_split)
testing_data <- testing(pdata_split)

# create xgb.DMatrix'
training_data_xgb_matrix <- xgb.DMatrix(training_data %>% select(-price) %>% as.matrix(), label = training_data$price)
test_data_xgb_matrix <- xgb.DMatrix(testing_data %>% select(-price) %>% as.matrix(), label = testing_data$price)

# create a regression
model_xgb <- xgboost(training_data_xgb_matrix, nrounds = 100, objective = "reg:squarederror")

# predict on test data
xgb_predictions <- predict(model_xgb, test_data_xgb_matrix)

# evaluate using rmse
test_rmse <- rmse(actual = testing_data$price, predicted = xgb_predictions)
test_rmse
# 1370.185
```

So, that is doing it step by step. My question is, can I somehow do this in a similar way to using the approach above during cross validation, particularity just adding a new column to a existing df / list column?

What is the 'tidy' way of evaluating a model on test data? Is it possible to start with training_data, append test data in a new column and start a workflow to reach the same result with rmse in it's own column following a call to mutate()?

```
training_data %>% 
  (add test data in a new column) %>%
  mutate(convert training data to a xgb.DMatrix) %>%
  mutate(convert test data to a xgb.DMatrix) %>%
  mutate(fit a regression model based on the training data xgb.DMatrix) %>%
  mutate(predict with the regression model on test data xgb.DMatrix) %>%
  mutate(calculate rmse)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: It might be possible but it would be very ugly. I think the step-by-step approach is clear and better.

Comment: Good to know. If my approach is already the 'right' way then so be it.